# How can I show a list of every thread running spawned by setTimeout/setInterval

Tags: javascript, multithreading, debugging

I want to do this either by pure javascript or any sort of console in a browser or whatever.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Further explanations:
I want to debug a library that does animations. I want to know if there's multiple timers created if there are multiple objects being animated.

Comment: Mike, can please you please add more detail?

Comment: do you want just a list of timeout id's running?  javascript doesn't use threads...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `setTimeout` doesn’t spawn a thread. If you want a list of all the timeout ids (so you can cancel them, for example) then see below:

---

I don’t think you can get a list of all timeout ids without changing the code when they are called. `setTimeout` returns an id—and if you ignore it, then it's inaccessible to your JavaScript. (Obviously the interpreter has access to it, but your code doesn't.)

If you could change the code you could do this:

```
var timeoutId = [];

timeoutId.push(setTimeout(myfunc, 100));
```

…Making sure that `timeoutId` is declared in global scope (perhaps by using `window.timeoutId = []`).

---

Just off the top of my head, but to reimplement `setTimeout` you’d have to do something like this:

```
var oldSetTimeout = setTimeout;
setTimeout = function (func, delay) {
    timeoutId.push(oldSetTimeout(func, delay));
}
```

This isn’t tested, but it gives you a starting point. Good idea, molf!

**Edit:** [aularon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627502/how-can-i-show-a-list-of-every-thread-running-spawned-by-settimeout-setinterval/3627962#3627962) gives a much more thorough implementation of the above idea.

Comment: You could actually redefine `setTimeout()` to store the ids in an array somewhere. That way no code has to be modified, you just have to inject some Javascript before it is executed.

Comment: @molf: NICE I will use the decorator pattern and hook-up the setTimeout and setInterval functions to find out :). Put your point as an anwer so I can accept it ;)

Comment: @Mike you generally don't need to use complicated patterns like that in dynamic languages.

Comment: Skilldrick has updated the answer with an example, so go ahead and accept this one. Remember that you should also modify `setInterval` and `clearTimeout` & `clearInterval` (to remove the ids from the array).

Comment: @Skilldrick: I want to peek inside another library

Answer (score 11):

Note that `setTimeout()` does not spawn new threads. Browser side scripting is not only single threaded, but the JavaScript evaluation shares the same single thread with the page rendering ([Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) apart).

Further reading:

- [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) by John Resig

You may want to build a timer manager yourself:

```
var timerManager = (function () {
   var timers = [];
   return {
      addTimer: function (callback, timeout) {
         var timer, that = this;
         timer = setTimeout(function () {
            that.removeTimer(timer);
            callback();
         }, timeout);
         timers.push(timer);
         return timer;
      },
      removeTimer: function (timer) {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         timers.splice(timers.indexOf(timer), 1);
      },
      getTimers: function () {
         return timers;
      }
   };
})();
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var t1 = timerManager.addTimer(function () {
   console.log('Timer t1 triggered after 1 second');
}, 1000);

var t2 = timerManager.addTimer(function () {
   console.log('Timer t2 triggered after 5 second');
   console.log('Number of Timers at End: ' + timerManager.getTimers().length);
}, 5000);

console.log('Number of Timers at Start: ' + timerManager.getTimers().length);
```

The above will display the following result in the console:

```
// Number of Timers at Start: 2
// Timer t1 triggered after 1 second
// Timer t2 triggered after 5 second
// Number of Timers at End: 0
```

Note that the `timerManager` implementation above uses the `Array.indexOf()` method. This has been added in JavaScript 1.6 and therefore not implemented by all browsers. However, you can easily add the method yourself by adding  the implementation from  [this Mozilla Dev Center article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that

Comment: The John Resig article is very useful, probably the best explanation of single thread asynchronous events I've come across so far. Thanks also for the excellent code.

Answer (score 8):

Finally done, it was interesting for me so I spent some time trying to come up with something, and [here it's](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm6Dc/)

It overrides browser's `setTimeout` and fill active status of current active calls in `window._activeSetTimeouts` hash, with `window._showCurrentSetTimeouts()` demo function that displays current `setTimeout` calls that are waiting.

```
if(typeof window._setTimeout =='undefined') {
window._setTimeout=window.setTimeout;

window._activeSetTimeouts={};
window._activeSetTimeoutsTotal=0;
window._setTimeoutCounter=0;
window._showCurrentSetTimeouts=function() {
    var tgt=document.getElementById('_settimtouts');
    if(!tgt) {
    tgt=document.createElement('UL');
    tgt.style.position='absolute';
    tgt.style.border='1px solid #999';
    tgt.style.background='#EEE';
    tgt.style.width='90%';
    tgt.style.height='500px';
    tgt.style.overflow='auto';
    tgt.id='_settimtouts';

    document.body.appendChild(tgt);
    }

    tgt.innerHTML='';
    var counter=0;
    for(var i in window._activeSetTimeouts) {
        var li=document.createElement('LI');
        li.innerHTML='[{status}] {delay} ({calltime})<br /><pre style="width: 100%; height: 5em; overflow: auto; background: {bgcolor}">{cb}</pre>'.f(window._activeSetTimeouts[i]);
        li.style.background=(counter++%2)?'#CCC' : '#EEB';
        tgt.appendChild(li);
    }
}
window.setTimeout=function(cb, delay) {
    var id = window._setTimeoutCounter++;
    var handleId = window._setTimeout(function() {
    window._activeSetTimeouts[id].status='exec';
    cb();
    delete window._activeSetTimeouts[id];
    window._activeSetTimeoutsTotal--;
    }, delay);

    window._activeSetTimeouts[id]={
    calltime:new Date(),
    delay:delay,
    cb:cb,
    status:'wait'
    };
    window._activeSetTimeoutsTotal++;
    return id;
}

//the following function is for easy formatting

String.prototype.f=function(obj) {
var newStr=this+'';
if(arguments.length==1) {
if(typeof(obj)=='string') {
    obj={x:obj};
}


for(var i in obj) {
    newStr=newStr.replace(new RegExp('{'+i+'}', 'g'), obj[i]+'');
}
newStr+='';

} else {
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    newStr=newStr.replace('{'+(i+1)+'}', arguments[i]);
    }
}
return newStr;
}
}

//following line for test
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) setTimeout(window._showCurrentSetTimeouts, 3000*i);
```

Comment: a bit late but thank you for that answer, very useful. However, I had to change the `cb();` call in 4th line of `window.setTimeout`: the submitted argument in setTimeout can be a function or the string representation of some javascript code.

Comment: *clap*... *clap*... *clap*.. *clap* *clap* *clap* *clap* *applause*. Amazing. Thanks so much for sharing!